# A question about full group C*-algebra

Tags: algebraic-topology, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

There is a quotation below:

$\qquad$The $full~group$ C*-algebra of $\Gamma$, denoted $C^{*}(\Gamma)$, is  the completion of $\mathbb{C}(\Gamma)$ with respect to the norm
$$\|x\|_{u}=\sup\limits_{\large{\pi}}\|\pi(x)\|,$$
where the supremum is taken over all (cyclic) *-representations $\pi: \mathbb{C}[\Gamma]\rightarrow B(H)$. **(Note that, since unitaries have norm one, the supremum is finite.)**

Well, **my question is: in the note, how can we conclude the supremum is finite from unitaries having norm one?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each $x$ is a  $\textit{finite}$ linear combination of elements from $\Gamma$. So since elements of $\Gamma$ get mapped to unitaries you have that

$x=\sum a_gu_g\Rightarrow\|x\|\leq \sum |a_g|\cdot\|u_g\|=\sum|a_g|<\infty $ since the sum if finite.

Comment: But, why does the elements of $\Gamma$ get mapped to unitaries?

Comment: That is the condition of being a $*$-representation. You have the adjoint in $\mathbb{C}\Gamma$ and the group elements are unitaries.